# how to use unity and websockets

Tags: node.js, unity-game-engine, websocket

Hey guys I'm making a unity webGL build with websocketsharp, https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp

Weird thing is it works fine when I run it from client, I can send and receive messages with nodeJS but when I upload the build to my server I get this error when I try to connect to the server

12/5/2021 6:53:40 PM|Fatal|.|System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): Could not resolve host 'mydomain.io'
Desktop.loader.js:1 at System.Net.Dns.Error_11001 (System.String hostName) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0

here is how I am connecting in C#

ws = new WebSocket("wss://mydomain.io:8000");
ws.SetProxy("https://mydomain.io/server", "", "");

I have no idea how to debug this. Why would it work in the unity editor but not when I upload to the server? Is websocketssharp the best way to communicate with a nodeJS server?

Comment: If you own this domain, configure your dns provider for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand in general `WebSocket` and networking `.Net / c#` classes are not [supported in WebGL](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-networking.html). You would need to either do the networking on `JavaScript` side or use `UnityWebRequest`.

---

In particular from the linked asset you are using

> It works with Unity Free, but there are some limitations:
>
> - Security Sandbox of the Webplayer (The server is not available in Web Player)
> - **WebGL Networking (Not available in WebGL)**

---

> Why would it work in the unity editor but not when I upload to the server?

-> Because within the Unity Editor you are still executing the pre-compiled `.Net` code on your standalone PC where these classes are fully supported. It isn't compiled into `WebGL` until you actually build your project.

Comment: thank you derHugo.  for anyone else having the same problem I found this, https://github.com/endel/NativeWebSocket, which works great!  no need to install packages or anything, just copy the files to your project.  i didn't even have to set a proxy, it just works right out of the box